# Change ToggleButton checked state background color UWP

Tags: uwp, custom-controls, windows-10-universal, togglebutton, uwp-xaml

I want to change the `ToggleButton` `Background` color when `IsChecked` is true. I tried changing the `VisualState` `Checked` to

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green" />
```

But this made the `Normal` state background fully transparent. I would like to bind the `Checked` `Background` color in `XAML`. How do I do this?

```
<!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton -->
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4" />
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
<Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
<Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
      <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
              <Storyboard>
                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltTransparentBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
              <Storyboard>
                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePointerOver">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePressed">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateDisabled">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

**Update**

I manage to change the Checked background color based on @DarkTemplar suggestion. Now for the binding part, I am create a `Custom Control` but my `Dependency Property` does not get applied.

```
public sealed class MyToggleButton : ToggleButton
{
    public MyToggleButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyToggleButton);
    }

    public Brush CheckedBackground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(CheckedBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CheckedBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CheckedBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(Application.Current.Resources["ToggleButtonBackgroundChecked"]));
```

In my XAML I have

```
<cc:MyToggleButton x:Name="Adjustments" Content="Adjustments" CheckedBackground="Red" />
```

Then in my `Style`

```
  <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=CheckedBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundChecked}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushChecked}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=CheckedBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedPointerOver}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPointerOver}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
        </Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback I managed to bind the `Checked` state `Background` color.

To set binding, I do not use the `SolidColorBrush` `Color` property. Just use the `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` property. So my `Storyboard` becomes

```
   <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding Path=CheckedBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundChecked}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushChecked}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding Path=CheckedBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedPointerOver}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPointerOver}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
```

`CheckedBackground` is the `DependencyProperty` created earlier in my `Templated Control` as shown in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the Background only when it is checked but want to keep it default colour when it is not checked, Change below in default template

```
<VisualState x:Name="Checked">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltTransparentBrush}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: That  what I did actually but the default colour became transparent.

Comment: If you see `VisualState`, it is only for `Checked` So your default state is not here. Check if your Default state is altered? or Maybe you can **Edit a Copy** Again and change just this and see if it works?

Comment: It's not altered. I copied and pasted the default from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299157.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Actually to change the checked color of a toggle button you might want to consider changing 2 visual state triggers, "Checked" and "CheckedPointerOver", in the XAML you showed those 2 triggers return different values for different objects and properties for example the "Checked" visual state trigger sets the "BorderBrush" property of the "ContentPresenter" control to transparent and the "Normal" visual state never touches the "ContentPresenter" control, which may explain why it becomes transparent.

check the "Checked" and "CheckedPointerOver" visual state triggers in this XAML:

```
    <Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle1" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundChecked}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushChecked}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundIndeterminate}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminate}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminate}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundIndeterminatePointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminatePointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminatePointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundIndeterminatePressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminatePressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminatePressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateDisabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundIndeterminateDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundIndeterminateDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderBrushIndeterminateDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

To Bind just replace the word "Green" with the resource you wish to bind to.

example:

replace this line:

```
   <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"/>
   </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
```

with this:

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
   <SolidColorBrush Color="{ThemeResource SystemChromeWhiteColor}"/>
</DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
```

Another option you can try is to try to set the BorderBrush property of the ContentPresenter control under the "Normal" visual state trigger:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Normal">
   <VisualState.Setters>
      <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(ContentPresenter.BorderBrush)" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
   </VisualState.Setters>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dark Templar. It works just that the binding part. I want o create a custom control for the `ToggleButton` but my `DependencyProperty` does not get applied. See my updated question. Thanks.